# receiving and uploading file without saving PHP

Tags: php, facebook

i'm using flash to upload image to php script which saves file on same directory and then uploads it to facebook album. That way i'm getting bunch of disk space used. 
Is there any way to bypass saving and just upload directly?

Script below:

```
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';
$upload_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';
$message ="";

$temp_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
$file_name = str_replace("","",$file_name);
$file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);
$file_path = $upload_dir.$file_name;

move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $file_path);
```

and then to upload I'm using:

```
 $attachment =  array (
    'access_token' => $appAccessToken,
    'message'=>  "NAME: ".$name.");
$attachment['image'] = '@' . realpath($file_path);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//get it
$upload_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';
$upload_url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/';
$message = "";

$temp_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['Filedata']['name']; 
$file_name = str_replace("","",$file_name);
$file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);
$file_path = $upload_dir.$file_name;

//save it
move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $file_path); 


//upload it to FB
$attachment =  array (
    'access_token' => $appAccessToken,
    'message'=>  "NAME: ".$name);
$attachment['image'] = '@' . realpath($file_path);
//more code to upload it....

//delete it
unlink($file_path);
```

- get it
- save it
- upload it to Fb
- delete it (with `unlink()` function)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, and I'm not sure about that, that you can send an attachment from the client computer (like C:\Folder1\Folder2\Image1.jpg) and you do not have to upload it into a server for sending it as an attachment.
Give it a shot.

Comment: Was thinking about it, but didnt want to hardcode access token which is needed for facebook upload ;) Thanks anyways!

Comment: You welcome.
Why not hardcoding it?
Ofcourse you can delete the file, as the prev answer said, buy the question is about the resources of the server required to upload and then delete...

Comment: Hardcoding access token into flash can be recovered with decompilers and then used :)